# Is there any way that I can use Application Customizer extension in whole site and only for one page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, splistitem, spfx-extensions

I have created a Application Customizer extension of permission for single page URL. Is there any way that I can use this extension in whole site?. If yes, how to do it?

Comment: Can you please explain your requirement in detail? How you created extension for "single page URL"?

Comment: I have created a application customizer extension regarding permissions to one single page. In extension we have to add page URL in serve.json. Is there any way that I can apply this extension to entire site, so whenever the user open the site he will be checked by the same permissions applied for the single page in sharepoint.

Comment: Follow this documentation for SPFx extension deployment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/serving-your-extension-from-sharepoint

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: Does this answers your question or you need more help with this question?